# Not able to get values from object within JSP

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I am getting the following exception when trying to get values from an item within my jsp.

Below is my error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/Dashboard] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/jsp/chartListFromDB.jsp at line 9

6:      <c:if test="${not empty chart_items}"></c:if>
7: 
8:      <c:forEach var="chartList" items="${chart_items}">
9:          <li><a href="/Dashboard/chart/displayChart/${chart_items.chartId}">${chart_items.chartName}</a>
10:             </li>
11:         </c:forEach>
12:     </ul>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "chartId" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
```

This is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/availableChartsFromDB", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String availableChartsFromDB(ModelMap model) {
    IChartBehaviour chartService = new ChartService();
    List<Chart> chart_items = chartService.getAvilableChartsFromDB();
    model.addAttribute("chart_items", chart_items);
    return "chartListFromDB";
}
```

This is my JSP

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@include file="header.jsp"%>
<div id="content_main">
<h3>Chart Selector ...</h3>
<ul>
    <c:if test="${not empty chart_items}"></c:if>

    <c:forEach var="chartList" items="${chart_items}">
        <li><a href="/Dashboard/chart/displayChart/${chart_items.chartId}">${chart_items.chartName}</a>
        </li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
</div>
<%@include file="footer.jsp"%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chartList.chartId. chartList is the iterator variable in chart_items list.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.I have tried to use chartList.chartId but am getting the same error returned.

Answer (score 0):

So after some more attempts and with the initial help from @Rahul Vedpathak 
I have now been able to fix this error.

As pointed out by Rahul - I was not using the iterator variable initally
I corrected this error but still had the same exception occur.

Second issue was I was trying to access the Chart object by reference instead of the getter method.

By changing

```
chartList.chartId
```

to

```
chartList.getChartId()
```

This resolved the my issue